# Round off some values of a tuple

Tags: python

I have tuples like this (  I not sure will it call a list of tuple or not ! )

```
ratings = [('5', 45.58139534883721), ('4', 27.44186046511628), ('3', 20.0), ('2', 5.116279069767442), ('1', 1.8604651162790697)]
```

I want to make second value round off ( or truncate, don't matter to me )up to 2 decimal place, like this:

```
[('5', 45.58), ('4', 27.44), ('3', 20.0), ('2', 5.11), ('1', 1.86)]
```

I tried something like this:

```
l = tuple([round(x,2) if isinstance(x, float) else x for x in ratings])
```

But this seems to be not working. What can I try?

Comment: The type of everything in ratings is `tuple`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round the 2nd element of your tuples only:

```
ratings = [('5', 45.58139534883721), ('4', 27.44186046511628), ('3', 20.0), ('2', 5.116279069767442), ('1', 1.8604651162790697)]
l = [(item[0],round(item[1],2)) for item in ratings]
# [('5', 45.58), ('4', 27.44), ('3', 20.0), ('2', 5.12), ('1', 1.86)]
```